# starmap быстрее операции в цикле?

Tags: python, модули

Вот код, решающий задачу [отсюда:](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximizing-xor/problem?utm_campaign=challenge-recommendation&utm_medium=email&utm_source=24-hour-campaign)

```
def maximizingXor(l, r):
    return max([i^j for i in range(l, r+1) for j in range(i, r+1)])
```

А вот мое, не такое изящное решение с использованием модулей:

```
from itertools import combinations, starmap
from operator import xor

# Complete the maximizingXor function below.
def maximizingXor(l, r):
    return max(starmap(xor, combinations(range(l,r+1),2)))
```

Оно не столь красиво, но оказалось быстрее на l=10, r=15:
%timeit дает *3.81 µs ± 156 ns*  на моем решении и  *8.67 µs ± 1.1 µs* per loop for solution without functions callingна решении без модулей.

Итак - вопрос. Почему быстрее? Ведь по идее код-то тотже. И более общий вопрос - в каких случаях целесообразнее пользоваться модулями, а в каких - писать в лоб?

Меня смущает тот факт, что конкретно здесь "в лоб" используется как бы встроенная операция `i^j`, что по идее должно было быть быстрее, чем делать то же, но с использыванием функции - оператора XOR. А поди ж ты )

P.S.: как выяснилось, моен решение оказалось немного "разумнее" прямолинейного и считает меньше элементов.
Более честно было бы сравнивать с вариантом `i+1` вместо `i`

```
def maximizingXor(l, r):
    return max([i^j for i in range(l, r+1) for j in range(i+1, r+1)])
```

однако улучшение оказалось не решающим, а именно %timeit дает *6.62 µs ± 83.4 ns*

P.P.S.:  Ну и для полноты картины - `tuple` просто добавим скобок:

```
def maximizingXor_t(l, r):
    return max(tuple(starmap(xor, combinations(range(l,r+1),2))))
```

здесь %timeit дает *4.11 µs ± 77.2 ns*. То есть генератор при засовывании в тупль - замедляется ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Меня смущает кое-что... А именно то, что результат `combinations(range(l,r+1),2)` и `for i in range(l, r+1) for j in range(i, r+1)` разный. А конкретнее, вариант с двойным `range` выдает больше элементов.

Переписал алгоритм и запустил:

```
from itertools import combinations

l=10
r=15

print(list(combinations(range(l,r+1),2)))
print([x for x in combinations(range(l,r+1),2)])
print([(i, j) for i in range(l, r+1) for j in range(i, r+1)])
```

Результат:

```
[(10, 11), (10, 12), (10, 13), (10, 14), (10, 15), (11, 12), (11, 13), (11, 14), (11, 15), (12, 13), (12, 14), (12, 15), (13, 14), (13, 15), (14, 15)]
[(10, 11), (10, 12), (10, 13), (10, 14), (10, 15), (11, 12), (11, 13), (11, 14), (11, 15), (12, 13), (12, 14), (12, 15), (13, 14), (13, 15), (14, 15)]
[(10, 10), (10, 11), (10, 12), (10, 13), (10, 14), (10, 15), (11, 11), (11, 12), (11, 13), (11, 14), (11, 15), (12, 12), (12, 13), (12, 14), (12, 15), (13, 13), (13, 14), (13, 15), (14, 14), (14, 15), (15, 15)]
```

---

Давайте сравним производительность combinations, combinations_with_replacement и вложенного цикла:

```
from timeit import timeit
NUMBER = 10000

elapsed = timeit("""\
list(combinations(range(l,r+1),2))
""", setup="""
from itertools import combinations
l=10
r=15
""", number=NUMBER)
print(elapsed)

elapsed = timeit("""\
list(combinations_with_replacement(range(l,r+1),2))
""", setup="""
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
l=10
r=15
""", number=NUMBER)
print(elapsed)

elapsed = timeit("""\
[x for x in combinations(range(l,r+1),2)]
""", setup="""
from itertools import combinations
l=10
r=15
""", number=NUMBER)
print(elapsed)

elapsed = timeit("""\
[x for x in combinations_with_replacement(range(l,r+1),2)]
""", setup="""
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
l=10
r=15
""", number=NUMBER)
print(elapsed)

elapsed = timeit("""\
[(i, j) for i in range(l, r+1) for j in range(i, r+1)]
""", setup="""
l=10
r=15
""", number=NUMBER)
print(elapsed)
```

Результат:

```
0.015679950736771395 : list(combinations(range(l,r+1),2))
0.019574358240705608 : [x for x in combinations(range(l,r+1),2)]
0.017971126274343937 : list(combinations_with_replacement(range(l,r+1),2))
0.023044554609408532 : [x for x in combinations_with_replacement(range(l,r+1),2)]
0.04071618284619548  : [(i, j) for i in range(l, r+1) for j in range(i, r+1)]
```

---

Как видно:

- `combinations` генерирует меньше элементов и быстрее `combinations_with_replacement`.
- `combinations_with_replacement` при таком же результате быстрее выполняется относительно генератора списка с вложенным циклами
- Код с генератором списка медленнее, чем такой же, но получаемый через вызов `list`: `list(...)` быстрее `[x for x in ...]`. Впрочем, тут пример не совсем подходящий -- в таких случаях в генераторе списка выполняются дополнительные действия, а не просто перекладывание значения.

Comment: хорошо замечено!

Comment: ну я сравнивал два решения. свое и чужое. Конкретно в этой задаче `x XOR х` равно нулю и его отбросил, взяв итератор комбинаций без повторения элементов. 
.
посчитал для варианта
`print([(i, j) for i in range(l, r+1) for j in range(i+1, r+1)])`

`6.62 µs ± 83.4 ns`
суть не меняется.
Спасибо - вопрос подправлю.

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, ваш выбор отбрасывания одинаковых значений правильный :) Кст, попробуйте замерить скорость combinations, combinations_with_replacement и двойного range. Интересно, что combinations_with_replacement  даст такой же результат как у range'ов, но будет практически такой же быстрый как combinations

Answer (score 3):

Я вот не отвечу на ваш вопрос, потому что, подозреваю, на него нет однозначного ответа.
Но вот то, что встроенные функции не всегда эффективнее модулей - это сущая правда, даже тогда, когда при написании этих модулей не стояла задача оптимизировать встроенные функции.

В частности, есть такая вещь в `numpy` как `type coercion` - приведение элементов списка при создании их него `numpy array` к одному типу, причем тип выбирается из типов элементов списка самый "неудобный" (то есть, например, если есть среди целочисленных элементов хотя бы один `float`, все элементы при создании массива приводятся к типу `float`). Я как-то ради эксперимента решил сравнить следующие варианты превращения списка целочисленных значений в строковые:

```
import numpy as np

lst=list(range(1000))

a=np.array(lst+[' '])[:-1]               #1
b=(np.array(lst+[' ']).tolist())[:-1]    #2 то же, что и №1, но приведенное к каноническому списку
c=list(map(str, lst))                    #3
d=[str(x) for x in lst]                  #4
print(b==c==d)   #-> True
                 # для чистоты эксперимента сравниваем результаты (все,
                 # кроме №1,потому что №1 - это numpy array)
```

А теперь самое интересное:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

vals=[]
codes=['a=list(range(1000));a=np.array(a+[' '])[:-1]',
       'a=list(range(1000));a=(np.array(a+[' ']).tolist())[:-1]',       
       'a=list(range(1000));a=list(map(str, a))',
       'a=list(range(1000));a=[str(x) for x in a]']

for code in codes:
    if 'np' in code:
        setup='import numpy as np'
    else:
        setup=''
    t = timeit.Timer(code, setup=setup)
    elapsed = t.timeit(number=10000)
    vals.append(elapsed)
```

И получаем интересную картину:

[image: coercion methods comparison]

То есть, `numpy type coercion` у меня в два раза (а без преобразования в список - в три) быстрее встроенной `map`.

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего причина в быстрой реализации функции [combinations()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) по сравнению с вложенными циклами:

```
In [19]: items = list(range(1000))

In [20]: %timeit [(i, j) for i in items for j in items]
110 ms ± 5.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [21]: %timeit list(combinations(items, 2))
43.9 ms ± 961 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [22]: %timeit list(combinations_with_replacement(items, 2))
46 ms ± 4.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Думаю, тут уместнее сравнивать вложенные циклы не с combinations, а с combinations_with_replacement. Но и combinations_with_replacement выдает почти такой же результат как и combinations. Быстрая реализация :)

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо, добавил тайминг для `combinations_with_replacement`

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, погодите ка... `max([starmap(xor, combinations(range(l,r+1),2))])` не сравнимо с `max(starmap(xor, combinations(range(l,r+1),2)))` у них и результат разный будет. В первом случае, расчетов не будет, поэтому сильная разница в результате. Думаю, вы имели ввиду `max(list(starmap(xor, combinations(range(l,r+1),2))))` и `max(starmap(xor, combinations(range(l,r+1),2)))`? В этом случае, первый вариант с `max(list(...` будет медленнее, чем просто `max(,,,)`

Comment: @gil9red я ошибся. )))
Спасибо - подправил все.